# How to print two strings on different lines with print()

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to print this Bookstore greeting on two line first line “hallo” second line “Cecil”

```html
for x in range(3,8,2):
 print(x)
 
system = 'bookstore'
greeting = 'Hallo, welcome to ' + str(system)
Cecil = " I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything"

hallo = greeting

print('hallo' \n + 'Cecil')
```

I'm getting this when I run it in pycharm

hallo n\ Cecil

I would like it to print like this:

Hallo, welcome to bookstore  
I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything

Answer (score 0):

```
system = 'bookstore'
greeting = 'Hallo, welcome to {}'.format(system) 
Cecil = " I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything"
hallo = greeting

print('{}\n{}'.format(hallo, Cecil))


Hallo, welcome to bookstore
I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(f"{greeting}\n{Cecil}") # f-string
# or
print(greeting + "\n" + Cecil) # concatenation
```

Both options will output what you'd like. `f"{variable}"` is the same as `"{}".format(variable)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
for x in range(3,8,2):
    print(x)

system = 'bookstore'
greeting = 'Hallo, welcome to ' + str(system)
Cecil = "I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything"

hallo = greeting

print(hallo + '\n' + Cecil)
```

produces the following output:

```
3
5
7
Hallo, welcome to bookstore
I'm Cecil let me know if you need help finding anything
```